# Should a large database table be split where it doesn't improve normalisation?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am currently building a database system for a company that stores a lot of information about their employees. Performance isn't a massive issue as there won't be a huge amount of employees in the database (>1000)

The database design that I have come up with so far has been normalized to an extent so employee data has been split in to separate tables where multiple data items need to stored for each employee, but there are a lot of fields which are primary key dependant so this has resulted in the main employee information table having around 50 columns.

Is this too many and should I try to group similar items into their own table e.g a table for contact information, a table for personal information, or is it better to leave it as is?

Comment: You don't have a performance problem . Beyond that, it's simply your design choice. There are Pros and Cons. If you have less than 100 columns I'd use a single table and place views over it. One factor that can influence table design (and seen this recently) is having some columns that get updated frequently (and in that case it can be  better to split those columns into another table)

Comment: @MitchWheat yes that's true, I don't think there will be any particular columns that will be updated more frequently than others. Thanks for the advice!